# Eip1559NotSupportedError

Tags: contract-deployment, eip-1559

1. "before each" hook for "deploy contract":
   Eip1559NotSupportedError: Invalid value given "Eip1559NotSupportedError". Error: Network doesn't support eip-1559.

This is my Inbox.sol code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.19;

contract Inbox {
string public message;

constructor(string memory initialMessage) { 
    message=initialMessage;
}

function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public{
    message=newMessage;
}
}
```

This is my compile.js code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const { stringify } = require('querystring');


const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf-8');

// console.log(solc.compile(source,1));

var input = {
language: 'Solidity',
sources: {
    'Inbox.sol' : {
        content: source
    }
},
settings: {
    outputSelection: {
        '*': {
            '*': [ '*' ]
        }
    }
}

};

module.exports =                 
JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol']        
['Inbox'];

console.log(module.exports);
```

this is my Inbox.test.js code:

```
const assert = require('assert'); 
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const { Web3 }  = require('web3'); 
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const{abi, evm} = require('../compile');



let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();

inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
.deploy({
    data: evm.bytecode.object,
    arguments: ['Halo']
})
.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
it('deploy contract', () =>{
    console.log(inbox);
})
})
```

And finally this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
"test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
"@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.1.12",
"assert": "^2.1.0",
"asset": "^0.4.13",
"ganache": "^7.8.0",
"ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
"mocha": "^10.2.0",
"solc": "^0.8.19",
"web3": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

I don't know what went wrong, I already ask chatgpt and it said I have to deactivate EIP-1559 by typing in cmd " ganache-cli --noVMEIP1559" or " ganache-cli --eip1559 false". But both are written "Unknown argument: noVMEIP1559"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for days.You can add to your code "gasPrice" as below

```
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
.deploy({
    data: evm.bytecode.object,
    arguments: ['Halo']
})
.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000',gasPrice:1000000000 });
});
```